# Update Index - update a search analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to update my search analyzer without closing the index.
Since it is a **search** analyzer I do not see a reason why should the index be closed (the data will not be re-indexed anyway).
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Not that I know about. You must close the index and reopen it after you make the changes.