# filter to get documents where the length of a nested document matches a number

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index that has a nested object called **plateformes**. The number of it sub-documents can vary, like this:

```
{
  "action" : "clean",
  "plateformes" : [
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme1",
        "status" : "failure"
    },
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme2",
        "status" : "succes"
    },
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme3",
        "status" : "succes"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "action" : "activate",
  "plateformes" : [
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme1",
        "status" : "failure"
    },
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme2",
        "status" : "succes"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "action" : "delete",
  "plateformes" : [
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme1",
        "status" : "succes"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to get only the documents where **plateformes** has exactly (let's say) **one** nested documents. With the example above, the query must return only this document:

```
{
  "action" : "delete",
  "plateformes" : [
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme1",
        "status" : "succes"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can add another field `plateformesCount` at indexing time in which you store the number of platformes your document contains. Then it's only a matter of comparing that field with some number, i.e. extremely fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand very well this way of doing. But i do not have the hand on the creation of the index. i have to deal with, or I must be sure that there is no other way to do it. Thank you for help

Comment: Then you can do as suggested in the deleted answer, but use `_source.plateformes.size() == 1` instead of `doc.platformes` and it should work. Just be aware that the performance will/might suffer.

Comment: ok. I will try this way first. Do you know how to implement this in java?

Comment: Yes, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007060/how-groovy-script-can-be-invoked-using-java-api-for-elasticsearch/32007549#32007549

Comment: Thank you @Val . Finally, I did as you first suggested. I succeeded in convincing my colleagues to add the field PlatformCount . And the problem was solved.

Comment: That's clearly the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another field `plateformesCount` at indexing time in which you store the number of `platformes` your document contains. Then it's only a matter of comparing that field with some number, i.e. extremely fast.

```
{
  "action" : "clean",
  "plateformesCount": 3,
  "plateformes" : [
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme1",
        "status" : "failure"
    },
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme2",
        "status" : "succes"
    },
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme3",
        "status" : "succes"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "action" : "activate",
  "plateformesCount": 2,
  "plateformes" : [
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme1",
        "status" : "failure"
    },
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme2",
        "status" : "succes"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "action" : "delete",
  "plateformesCount": 1,
  "plateformes" : [
    {
        "plateforme" : "myplateforme1",
        "status" : "succes"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if all object has status , you can use exist to check if object exist, then use sum to calc count,then use script score to choose the condition you want. like below code

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "plateformes",
          "query": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "plateformes.status"
            }
          },
          "score_mode": "sum"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "_score == 1 ? 1 : 0"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  },
  "min_score": 1
}
```