# Filter by length of nested array

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my mapping:

```
{"field_name": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {...},
    "type": "nested"
}}
```

And I am trying to filter only documents which have at least one `field_name`.

I tried:

```
{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [ { "script" : {
              "script" : {
                   "inline": "doc['field_name'].length >= 1",
                   "lang": "painless"
        } } ]
    }
} }
```

But elasticsearch is screaming at me about `No field found for [field_name] in mapping with types [type_name]`.

I also tried to wrap the previous query into a `nested` but didn't work either:

```
{ "nested": {
     "path": "field_name",
     "query": {
          "bool": {
              "filter": [ {
                   "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "inline": "doc['field_name'].length >= 1",
                            "lang": "painless"
                        }
                   }
              } ]
         }
    }
} }
```

This gave the same error as above.

Any ideas?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721935/filter-to-get-documents-where-the-length-of-a-nested-document-matches-a-number/40726639#40726639

Comment: I saw that but I cannot change the index.

Comment: Then you can use the other suggestions, i.e. use `_source.field_name.size() >= 1` in your script, but the performance might suffer.

Comment: I think ill do that but I wanted good performances :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing is adding a field `my_array_length` during construction time. Like that I can just filter by the value of this field.

Answer (score 6):

if all object has same field , you can use exist to check if object exist, then use sum to calc count,then use script score to choose the condition you want. like below code

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "field_name",
          "query": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "field_name.same_field"
            }
          },
          "score_mode": "sum"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "_score >= 1 ? 1 : 0"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  },
  "min_score": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach would be using `exists` term for each of the fields:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "field_name.dynamic"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "field_name.properties"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "field_name.type"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You define `should` clause with `minimum_should_match` and get only relevant documents.

See [exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html), [bool-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: it doesnt work because the field exist, it is just empty. length =0

Comment: so, why not using `regexp`?