# unable to find script [testfile] in cluster state in elastic search 8.9 v

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have created a file ie., `testfile.painless`

```
ctx._source.b_id=params.b_id;
```

and just placed the `testfile.painless` file in the config/scripts folder on cluster node and then tried with `_update_by_query`

```
{
    "script": {
        "id":  "testfile",
              "params": {
            "b_id": "1W"
        }

    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "a_core": "71"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "cid": "3IM"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran the update query then I received with unable to find script [testfile] in cluster state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts cannot be stored in files anymore, you need to store them in the cluster state like this:

```
PUT _scripts/testfile
{
   "script": {
      "source": "....source code of your script..."
   }
}
```

And then you can run your update query like you do now.

Comment: { "error": {"root_cause": [{"type": "script_exception","reason": "compile error","script_stack": ["params['b_id']","      ^---- HERE"],"script": "params['branch_id']",lang": "painless", "type": "script_exception","reason": "compile error","script_stack": ["params['b_id']","      ^---- HERE"

Comment: Ok, that means it's working now and that your script has issues, but that would be a different question in which you can show the content of your script

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But do I need to manually execute the script file at the cluster level every time any change in the script file?

Comment: How about in prod environments if we are calling to script file using update by query from java program?

Comment: Glad it worked out! Every time you change your script you need to store it again using the command I gave you, i.e. `PUT _scripts/testfile`. When done, the script is compiled and available in the cluster state.

Comment: yes did it thanks val !